# Why does the code editor not see objects defined in a data module

Tags: delphi, ide

Using the Community version of Delphi  I have a database defined in a datamodule (DataMod), and also the dataset form401ds defined in that datamodule. I also obviously have a USES statement for DataMod defined in the main unit. I also have a TIBSQL (IBSQL1) defined in DataMod. I am attempting to programmatically define that dataset with the code below. The italic code is flagged with a red underline by the code editor. In addition if I type DataMod. Into the code editor I don’t get the list of objects which are defined in DataMod as I would expect. Why not, and what am I doing wrong?

```
var sqltext,
listboxtext,
primaryindivtext,
title    :  string;
queryeof : boolean;
begin
sqltext := 'drop table ';
sqltext := sqltext+'form401ds;';
sqltext := sqltext+'create table form401ds (';
sqltext := sqltext+'sourcelistno integer,';
sqltext := sqltext+'sourceassociation integer,';
sqltext := sqltext+'sourceseqno integer,';
sqltext := sqltext+'sourceid varchar(20),';
sqltext := sqltext+'id varchar(20),';
sqltext := sqltext+'title varchar(40),';
sqltext := sqltext+'primaryindiv varchar(40) );';
DataMod.*IBSQL1.SQL.text* := sqltext;
DataMod.*IBSQL1.ExecSQL*;
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! If I understand well, your problem is seeing the red squiggle. OK, but does the code compile correctly? If not, what is the EXACT error message the compiler issue, on which line?

Comment: And please show your code, do not just describe it. E.g., how are your objects declared, ``private``, ``public`` etc.?

Comment: Type the unit name into a method/procedure etc  and do a build - it should ask about adding the unit / data module to the uses clause. Answer yes and code completion should now work. The unit uses reference will be added under `implementation`.

Answer (score 1):

For units already part of the project referencing them in code and then doing a build will prompt asking if you want the unit added to the uses clause. Trying to built code with the below with a Unit2 in the project:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Unit2.
end;
```

Gets a dialog:

[image]

Answering yes the implementation section is updated to include the unit:

```
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses Unit2;
```

Code completion will now work for things defined in the other unit.

Comment: The datamodule in my project is called DATAMOD, and therefore DATAMOD appears in my USES statement. However the NAME property of that datamodule is DATAMODULE1. When I use DATAMODULE1 as the first qualifier when referring to objects the red underlines disappear and code completion works ok. Thank you to all who commented about this problem, your comments prompted me to look at the problem afresh, and thereby to crack it.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a database defined in a datamodule (`DataMod`)
> I also obviously have a `USES` statement for `DataMod` defined in the main unit

It appears you are mixing unit name and data module name. Your description hints that the units name is

```
unit DataMod;
```

If this is the case, then the data module class can not be `TDataMod` (and instance can not be `DataMod`).

Perhaps the name of the data module class is `TDataModule2`. Then the interface part would look like this:

```
unit DataMod;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, IBX.IBSQL;

type
  TDataModule2 = class(TDataModule)
    IBSQL1: TIBSQL;
  private
  public
  end;
```

And then the instance would be declared as:

```
var
  DataModule2: TDataModule2;
```

Finally, to address the `TIBSQL` from your forms unit you would need to

add the unit name to the `uses` clause in the `implementation` section of the form unit:

```
uses DataMod;
```

refer to the `TIBSQL` instance as follows

```
DataModule2.IBSQL1.SQL.text := '...';
```